# In Islam, should an undergraduate care about general education courses in Western universities?

Tags: sharia

In the Western universities, students supposed to learn things unrelated to their major.
What is Islamic perspective on this?

Comment: Why would you think this is an Un-Islamic practice?

Comment: I don't want to wasting time

Comment: Again, how is that un-Islamic?

Comment: (And those who turn away from Al-Laghw.) refers to falsehood, which includes Shirk and sin, and any words or deeds that are of no benefit.  http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2482&Itemid=78

Comment: But this is education. It might not be subject that *you* personally like. If we learned only what we like, instead of what we *need* it would be a sad state of affairs indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Islam doesn't put any restrictions on the kind of courses you take except for [classes that lead to evil](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/113970). There's no harm in taking classes that are not part of your major as for as they benefit you in a good and halal way.

Comment: You're right. Eventually I learnt and accepted that those classes are beneficial. There are several factors to consider such as inshaAllah 1.we learn faster and faster when older (to certain extent)[e.g. learning curve], 2.we learn more specific things when older and having broad base understanding is useful in multidisciplinary research etc. (I'm aiming for PhD inshaAllah)  etc.